# Find the maximum sum of a column of two dimensional arrays in c

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, pointers, malloc

I have two dimensional arrays and I want to sum of column, and find the max of sum. I use `malloc` for array for initialization. When the program finishes I want to print the result, but result is different from what I expect.

it's result->

```
2 sum is -> 2 max is -> 4201200
5 sum is -> 7 max is -> 4201200
6 sum is -> 13 max is -> 4201200
8 sum is -> 8 max is -> 4201200
9 sum is -> 17 max is -> 4201200
6 sum is -> 23 max is -> 4201200
5 sum is -> 5 max is -> 4201200
9 sum is -> 14 max is -> 4201200
2 sum is -> 16 max is -> 4201200
max is 4201200 column 0
```

this is my code --->

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    int row = 3, col = 5;
    int *a = (int *)malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
            *(a + i * col + j) = (rand() % (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;   

    printf("The array elements are:\n");
    
    int sad;
    int max1;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            printf("%d ", a[j * col + i]);
            sum += a[j * col + i];
            printf("sum is -> %d max is -> %d\n", sum, max1);
        }
        if (sum > max1) {
            printf("max is detected");
            max1 = sum;
            sad = j;
            sum = 0;
        }
        sum = 0;
    }
    printf("max is %d column %d", max1, sad);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

thank you!

Comment: `max1` is not initialized

Comment: @Odysseus why? i have max1 out of loop

Comment: It needs to be initialized before the loop.

Comment: @IanAbbott But is not it? First I have max1 and then loop.

Comment: @kokiwebaaa With `int max1;` it has no initial value and therefore equals something random still within memory. As a consequence `if (sum>max1)` might not be `true` and it won't get assigned

Comment: @kokiwebaaa So what value does `max1` have at the `if(sum>max1){` line during the first iteration of the loop?

Comment: You should also initialize `sad` in case none of the columns sum > 0. I suggest initializing `sad=0;` and `max1=INT_MIN;`.

Comment: so give  i max1 and sum the value 0 before loop?

Comment: Initial `max1=0;` is OK if the sums are always positive, otherwise `max1=INT_MIN;` is better.

Comment: Aside: `sizeof(int) * row * col` will not overflow as readily as `row * col * sizeof(int)`.  Useful when `row` or `col` are large.

Comment: By the way, the outer loop termination condition (for the column summing loops) should be `i < col` (not `i < row`), and when a new maximum sum is found, `sad=j;` is wrong. It should be `sad=i;`.

Comment: `for (j = 0; j < row; j++) {` is suspicious.  Do you want `for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica i want sum of column

Comment: https://pastebin.com/109CkXqT please see edited code and result. this is not correct

Comment: @kokiwebaaa Iterating both `i, j` up to `row` with `for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {  for (j = 0; j < row; j++) {` makes little sense.

Comment: To avoid confusion, I suggest using loop index variable `r` to iterate over rows, and `c` to iterate over columns.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica when i change row to col after i have this result and why? https://pastebin.com/t9U0U6D2

Comment: If you have a standard C compiler change the code to `int (*a)[col] = malloc(row * col * sizeof(int));` ... `a[i][j] = something;` Far more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`max1` is unintialized, hence the test `if (sum > max1)` is meaningless and `max1` may not be updated correctly. In your case, `max1` happened to have the value `4201200`, but the behavior is undefined and this could have been any value or even a trap value on some systems.

Since all matrix elements are positive, you can initialize `max1` to `0`, otherwise you would use `INT_MIN` defined in `<limits.h>` or add a test for the first column.

Furthermore, the index values `i` and `j` are swapped in the second loop and the loop test is incorrect too.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {

    int rows = 3, cols = 5;
    int *a = (int *)malloc(rows * cols * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            a[i * cols + j] = (rand() % (10 - 1 + 1)) + 1;   
        }
    }

    printf("The array elements are:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            printf(" %2d", a[i * cols + j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    int max_col = 0;
    int max_sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            sum += a[i * cols + j];
        }
        printf("sum of column %i is -> %d\n", j, sum);
        if (j == 0 || sum > max_sum) {
            printf("max is detected\n");
            max_sum = sum;
            max_col = j;
        }
    }
    printf("max is %d column %d\n", max_col, max_sum);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's infinite loop

Comment: @kokiwebaaa: my bad. I updated the answer with safer `for` loops that define their index variable. This would have caught the typo on `i++` instead of `j++`.

Comment: thank you very much